# I am getting this error when I am trying to install Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install [countvar package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/countvar/0.2.2) but I am always receiving the above error. I have updated my installation tools but I still receiving it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times this is resolved by the following approach

```
 python -m pip install --upgrade pip
 pip install "package-name"
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this and it is up to data but still I got the same error